# Join along a non-coordinate dimension in xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I'm trying to join a set of values from one `DataArray`, to another. They should join based on a non-dimension coordinate of the first. I think this should be easy but I can't seem to work it out.

The first array:

```
In [4]: primary=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(4), dims=list('a'))
   ...: primary.coords['group'] = (('a',), [0,0,1,1])
   ...: primary
   ...: 
Out[4]: 
<xarray.DataArray (a: 4)>
array([ 0.27772841,  0.06126117,  0.51753086,  0.35994987])
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) int64 0 1 2 3
    group    (a) int64 0 0 1 1
```

The second array:

```
In [5]: secondary=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(2), dims=['group'], coords={'group': [0,1]})
   ...: secondary
   ...: 
Out[5]: 
<xarray.DataArray (group: 2)>
array([ 0.75944366,  0.90325489])
Coordinates:
  * group    (group) int64 0 1
```

How can I do `primary - secondary` such that the arrays are joined along the `group` dimension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `groupby` the first *but not apply an aggregation to it*:

```
In [6]: primary.groupby('group') - secondary
Out[6]: 
<xarray.DataArray (a: 4)>
array([-0.48171525, -0.69818249, -0.38572403, -0.54330502])
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) int64 0 1 2 3
    group    (a) int64 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure this one out yourself :).