# Join using a non-index coord in xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I'm trying to do a 'join' in xarray, but using a non-index coordinate on one of the items. I *think* this shouldn't be too difficult, but I've been spinning.

I have a Dataset indexed on `'a'` with a coord on `'b'`, and a DataArray indexed on `'b'`:

```
In [17]: ds=xr.Dataset(dict(a=(('x'),np.random.rand(10))), coords=dict(b=(('x'),list(range(10)))))

In [18]: ds
Out[18]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 10)
Coordinates:
    b        (x) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Dimensions without coordinates: x
Data variables:
    a        (x) float64 0.3634 0.2132 0.6945 0.5359 0.1053 0.07045 0.5945 ...

In [19]: da=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(10), dims=('b',), coords=dict(b=(('b'),list(range(10)))))

In [20]: da
Out[20]:
<xarray.DataArray (b: 10)>
array([0.796987, 0.275992, 0.747882, 0.240374, 0.435143, 0.285271, 0.753582,
       0.556038, 0.365889, 0.434844])
Coordinates:
  * b        (b) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Can I add `da` onto my dataset, by joining on `ds.b` equalling `da.b`?

This is somewhat related to [Join along a non-coordinate dimension in xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229722/join-along-a-non-coordinate-dimension-in-xarray), but I don't want to do any arithemtic, and the final result should be dimensioned on `'a'`, not `'b'`

Thanks!

Edit: as requested by @DSM, the output would be:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 10)
Coordinates:
    b        (x) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Dimensions without coordinates: x
Data variables:
    a        (x) float64 0.3634 0.2132 0.6945 0.5359 0.1053 0.07045 0.5945 ...
    da       (x) float64 0.796987, 0.275992, 0.747882, 0.240374, 0.435143 ...
```

Edit2: here's an example answer with string keys and where `ds` has only a subset of keys. (I don't think this approach works if `da` has a subset, though additional aligning could help)

```
In [23]: da=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(5), dims=('b',), coords=dict(b=(('b'),list('edcba'))))


In [27]: da
Out[27]:
<xarray.DataArray (b: 5)>
array([0.174843, 0.953963, 0.092538, 0.749569, 0.780823])
Coordinates:
  * b        (b) <U1 'e' 'd' 'c' 'b' 'a'


In [25]: ds=xr.Dataset(dict(a=(('x'),np.random.rand(4))), coords=dict(b=(('x'),list('abcd'))))


In [24]: ds
Out[24]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 5)
Coordinates:
    b        (x) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'
Dimensions without coordinates: x
Data variables:
    a        (x) float64 0.7586 0.3529 0.5936 0.741 0.6344


In [26]: da.sel(b=ds.b)
Out[26]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4)>
array([0.780823, 0.749569, 0.092538, 0.953963])
Coordinates:
    b        (x) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

Comment: Could you edit to include the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead of a list/vector of indexers, you provide a DataArray, the array will be reshaped to the coordinate of the indexer:

```
In [5]: da.sel(b=ds.b)
Out[5]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 10)>
array([0.327058, 0.904678, 0.455166, 0.67915 , 0.426856, 0.295434, 0.272206,
       0.630101, 0.447915, 0.157343])
Coordinates:
    b        (x) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

You can use this in assignment to join `da` on `ds.b`:

```
In [6]: ds['da'] = da.sel(b=ds.b)

In [7]: ds
Out[7]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 10)
Coordinates:
    b        (x) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Dimensions without coordinates: x
Data variables:
    a        (x) float64 0.9338 0.9901 0.4498 0.49 0.3023 0.2622 0.03598 0.2 ...
    da       (x) float64 0.3271 0.9047 0.4552 0.6791 0.4269 0.2954 0.2722 ...
```

The xarray docs on [More advanced indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) provide some good examples of this feature.

Comment: Thank you for having a go. On reflection, are you sure this is only seems to be working because the coord labels are ints being used as index positions? This no longer works if I change 0-9 to a-j.

Comment: This would still work if the `b` coordinate were the same in both datasets. If you'd like to use positional indexing you can use `da.isel`

Comment: Thanks! I added an example of that working. Appreciate you help working through this.

Comment: Definitely! And if da has a subset of keys, `da.sel(b=ds.b)` will certainly raise a `KeyError`. If you'd like it to return `NaN` or a padded value you could use [`da.reindex`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.reindex.html) to reindex the array before selecting the data.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Are you under a different name on GH? Or you don't contribute to xarray regularly on there?

Comment: I'm under the same name on github, and am not an xarray core contributer. #lifegoals :)

Comment: You know xarray better than most!